# Google Apps Script setFontFamily("string") for created Doc

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I've created a script which processes a form and creates and emailed document (and pdf). I can't seem to get any results attempting to set the font though (defaults to Arial). My understanding is that font strings are taken as argument, rather than ENUM, so I'm not sure if I'm misspelling strings (e.g. "Cormorant Garamond") or what. Alternatively, was curious how I might use a stylized template to format paragraphs (text and lists)

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create('Test ' + name).addEditor(email);;
var body = doc.getBody();
// Set the document font.
body.editAsText().setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
```

Comment: Think I solved by simply moving command to end of script after all paragraphs/lists have been appended (before saving and closing/emailing). Would still be interested in using a stylized template...

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by ```use a stylised template to format paragraphs```? Do you mean to apply a style trhough Apps Script to a paragraph like in [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setattributesattributes)?